# Update users custom profile fields

Tags: functions

Ok guys, i have problem when using some trics from here or other sites. I`m trying to use this method of adding custom user fields. But, when i add this, everytime i save it`s all ok, but when i come back to edit something different in user profile, those new fields just goes blank, and if i did not input again my data in those fields and save my profile, those fields goes blank in DB. So, something is not ok that need to show me what i did just saved.

As I told, it`s all ok until i open again my profile for editing.

Ok, here is code, http://pastebin.com/u9syYRF3

Comment: @Саша: Can you update your question and add the code you're using to add the fields? This sounds like you just need to set the value of the new fields to the current DB value, if it exists.

Comment: Jan is right, you need to add more / clarify your question otherwise it's hard to understand for all those who don't know your site's code.

Comment: There, code pasted on pastebin. If you need to test what i told, i can make you an user on my blog.

Comment: Jan has you covered, see answer... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the value of the `<textarea>` in a `value` attribute, but for a `<textarea>` you must put it between the two tags:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="adsense_336" id="adsense_336" class="regular-text" ><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'adsense_336', $user->ID ) ); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the answer.... i believe the first `textarea` should be referring to `input`.. ;)

Comment: @t31os: Ah, it was a confusing sentence. Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Oh, thanks ! I totaly missed what i want to do. Thanks again to both of you ! Working now like an charm !